# Acces node content via Javascript from a non-drupal site

Tags: xml, json, dom, drupal, traversal

I need to access node contents (contanined in a view from Views module) of a drupal t installation from a non drupal site. I think a combination of XML/JSON traversed via Javascript /JQUERY will be a good option but i've have no idea on how to do this. I will greatly appreciate any ideas!

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,

Oliver

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you need to get an RSS feed from your Drupal site to your other one? That's easily done with the Views module. In the same way you make a new Page or Block for your View, you can make a Feed. Once that's done, the other site can read in the RSS and do whatever you want with that XML.